# Enemy AI Stop enemy in certain distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

Hello i was trying to make my enemy stop in front of player using `if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > minDistance)`

But that doesnt work as i intended. Enemy should start following the player in certain range and than stop in front of him. That worked fine with `if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= range)`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Health;
    public Transform player;
    public float range;
    public float speed;
    public Animator anim;
    public Transform goblinRange;
    public float attackRangeGoblin;
    public LayerMask whatIsPlayer;
    public int damage;
    private float timeBtwAttack;
    public float startTimeBtwAttack;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= range)          
        {
            anim.SetBool("GWalking", true);
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * 
  Time.deltaTime);

            Collider2D[] playerToDamage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(goblinRange.position, 
  attackRangeGoblin, whatIsPlayer);
            for (int i = 0; i < playerToDamage.Length; i++)
            {
                playerToDamage[i].GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().TakeDamage(damage);               
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            Idle();
        } 
    } 

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void Idle()
    {
        anim.SetBool("GWalking", false);        
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int Damage)
    {
        Health -= Damage;
        Debug.Log("Damage Taken");
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(goblinRange.position, attackRangeGoblin);
    }

    private void Attack()
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("goblinAttack");        
    }     
}
```

So i need enemy to stop in front my player and start attack animation, but i dont know how to implement the `if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > minDistance)` to my code without deleting the "<= range". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > minDistance)` means "if the opponent is further than minDistance from the player`, are you sure thats what you want? Are you telling to only run when that is true?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `range` and `minDistance` checks are not mutually-exclusive ("one or the other"). They can both be present and coexist:

```
//Avoid redundancy, write less, and make things more readable
var distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

//If within range..
if (distance <= range) {
    //If not within minDistance..
    if(!(distance <= minDistance)) {
        //Move
    }

    //If within minDistance (incl. after moving, above)..
    if (distance <= minDistance) {
        //Attack
    }
}
//If not within range..
else {
    //Idle
}
```

---

There are several other problems with the code:

1. You should follow a naming convention:

   - If your variables and parameters are going to be camelCase, then `Health` should be `health`, `GWalking` should be `gWalking`, and `Damage` should be `damage`.
2. Names should be descriptive:

   Skipping a few characters for typing is not worth the headaches of you or someone else (us, for instance) having to decypher your code.

   - Avoid ambiguity. `anim` can refer to an **anim***ator* or an **anim***ation*. Use `animator`.
   - Avoid acronyms. In `GWalking`, what does the `G` stand for? --- **G**oblin. I know. Problem is: I know from inference from the rest of the code; not from the name itself. Use `goblinWalking` instead.
   - Avoid acronym-like shortenings like `Btw` instead of `Between`. They are bad for the same reason 'G' was.
3. Be consistent:

   - Use the same naming structure for similar stuff. Decide upon a scheme, and follow it. Don't put `GWalking` in one spot and `goblinAttack` in another. If "`subjectAction`" is the structure, use `goblinWalking`, `goblinAttack` and so on.
   - Use the same structural order in names. If your subject is going to be at the start, as in `goblinRange`, then don't put it at the end elsewhere, as in `attackRangeGoblin`. Use `goblinAttackRange`.
   - If the class is "Enemy", "Goblin" stuff should not be there. All goblins *might* be enemies, but not all enemies might be goblins. Your class may be generic to all enemies, or specific to goblins; not both. Name it `Goblin`; or remove "goblin" stuff from it's elements.
4. Name variables for what they are, not for what they do:

   - `whatIsPlayer` to `playerLayerMask`.
5. Be resourceful in naming (aka: "Descriptive doesn't mean verbose!"):

   - `timeBtwAttacks` to `attackInterval`.
6. Try to group related stuff.

After fixes, it should look like this:

```
//External(?) dependencies
public Transform player;
public LayerMask playerLayerMask; //From: whatIsPlayer

//Internal dependencies
public Animator animator; //From: anim

//Settings
public int health; //From: Health
public float range;
public float speed;
public int damage;
public float attackInterval; //From: timeBtwAttack

//Gobling stuff (probably redundant/unnecessary)
public Transform goblin; //From: goblinRange
public float goblinAttackRange; //From: attackRangeGoblin

//Used in the answer, as infered from the question
public float minDistance; //Probably what 'goblinAttackRange' is.
```

---

Other fixes:

- `FixedUpdate` is for physics stuff. `if (health <= 0) { Destroy(gameObject); }` should be in `Update` (with addition of a `return`), if the current structure is to be followed. If not, then it should behave reactivelly to changes to health, and thus in `TakeDamage`.
- Be consistent in code. Don't use `anim.SetBool("GWalking", true)` in one place, then `Idle()` in another. Both should be methods (`Idle()` ***and*** `Walk()`) or both should be `SetBool` calls.
- Is `Transform goblin` a separate transform? If it's not, just use `transform` like you did in `Vector2.Distance`.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the `minDistance` check inside of your `range` check as seen below:

```
if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= range)
{
    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= minDistance)
    {
        //Attack
    }
    else
    {
        //Chase
    }
}
```

This way, the enemy will chase the player as long as it's within the chase range, but not yet close enough to attack. It will stop chasing and start attacking once it's within the attack range.

Comment: Minor issue, but this is not completely consistent with the behaviour from the question's code. There, an attack would happen in the same frame the position became within `minDistance`. This, however, will only trigger the attack on the next frame. --- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931471/1253136) covers pseudo-code trully equivalent to the question's, but took a lot longer to write as I covered all(?) other problems as well. --- Other than that, the answer is generally correct. +1

Answer (score -2):

try using

```
if((transform.position, player.position).magnitude <range)
```

instead of

```
if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= range)
```

Comment: Did you mean `(transform.position - player.position).magnitude`? --- It doesn't make a difference anyway, as `Vector2.Distance` serves the same purpose, [and has equivalent code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/9034442437e6b5efe28c51d02e978a96a3ce5439/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector2.cs#L188).